# I can't find command Flutter: Launch Emulator on VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, vscode-extensions

I'm currently learning to make an application with flutter. I saw a tutorial video, when he trying to open the emulator, in the command palette he wrote Flutter: Launch Emulator.he's on MacOS.
on Windows OS when I try to do the same, I can't find the command Flutter: Launch emulator.

does this command only exist on the MacOS platform?
but in the video tutorial hes not only has an emulator for ios but also for android, a Pixel device.

Comment: OOH Sorry, the command 'Flutter: Launch emulator' will appear when theres already emulator installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command to launch emulator for both MACOS and Windows.
It is
`flutter emulators --launch Nexus_6P`
 (Nexus_6P is the type of emulator that already created on VSCode or Android studio)
In case you didn't create any. Use this command
`flutter emulators --create Nexus_6P`